# Storing Listbox selection as variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to store the selection from two separate listboxes as variables that are referenced as workbooks. I am using the following to loop through each listbox and identify the selection.

fileOne is set as a variable:

```
Dim fileOne as Workbook
```

The error is a Run time error '13': Type mismatch at the line where the name of the workbook (listBx1) is passed to the Workbooks object in the fileOne variable from my original post. Both listBx1 and listBx2 are declared in the CommandButton1_Click() public sub and in the code where they are being called as workbook names.

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Item1 As Long, Item2 As Long

For Item1 = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(Item1) = True Then
        listBx1 = ListBox1.Text
    End If
Next

For Item2 = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox2.Selected(Item2) = True Then
        listBx2 = ListBox2.Text
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

The code with the error is just setting the text from the listbox into a variable:

```
Set fileOne = Workbooks(listBx1)
```

I'm not sure if the userform is being unloaded before the variables are set or if .Text isn't the proper object for the listbox item.

How do I store the selection from a listbox as a variable?

Comment: what is fileOne? Whats the error message? where is listBx1 declared? and so on.... -1

Comment: fileOne is set as a  variable:

    Dim fileOne as Workbook

The error is a Run time error '13': Type mismatch at the line where the name of the workbook (listBx1) is passed to the Workbooks object in the fileOne variable from my original post.

Both listBx1 and listBx2 are declared in the CommandButton1_Click() public sub and in the code where they are being called as workbook names

Comment: You will only get `13` when `listBx1` is null. You need to check the variable scope for `listBx1`. Before passing it to workbook make sure its not null.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. In that case, it seems that the code Then portion of the code is not doing what I'm expected it to do.

In the loops above, do you happen to know how to grab the True selection and call it in the variables? Ie. listBx1 = "What item is selected in the list box"

Does it matter that the code is stored within the command button click sub in the userform?